# Sharing AngularJS models

Tags: angularjs, models

I have an Angular controller `CanvasController` modelling a canvas onto which "widgets" can be placed.

The controller maintains a simple array, `_currentWidgets`, of object literals that correspond to the widgets currently on the canvas. e.g. `[ {id: 1} ]`.

A `CanvasDirective` is tied to `CanvasController`, with an Angular watch placed on the array `currentWidgets` in the link function. This means the canvas is re-rendered when widgets are added and removed.

The canvas template contains the following line to render the widgets:

```
<div ng-include="'widget-template'" ng-repeat="widgetModel in currentWidgets" />
```

And widget template is defined as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="widgetController as widgetCtrl">foo</div>
```

It is my understanding that this means that whenever a new item is added to currentWidgets a new instance of `WidgetController` is instantiated by Angular for use by the new widget.

My question - how can I share the model created in the `CanvasController` with the new instance of the `WidgetController` instantiated when a widget it added? Or would this not be idiomatic and should I simply instantiate a separate model for the widget inside the `WidgetController`?

Answer (score 1):

In your case it might already be shared already. See prototypal inheritance.
As I understand your widgets should have scopes that are child to the canvas directive, right?

A quick solution is to create a method in the parent, javascript's prototypal inheritance should lookup the method from the child to the parent's.

Or send events...

The controller's role is to extend a scope, perhaps from the $rootScope.

That means your controller's scope is a child of the $rootScope. You can try $rootScope.$broadcast() or scope.$emit(). That's one way, by sending events.

$emit() will send events going upward to the $rootScope from the child scope.
$broadcast() will send events going downward from the parent to the descendants.